# Dynamically assigning value to structure variable

Tags: c++, variables, struct

I am trying to dynamically assign values from a file to variables in a structure, but can't figure out how to do it.  I have a structure:

```
struct abc {
 int age = 0;
 string name = "whatever";
} *ABC;
```

I also have a function that loops through a file that can read these values so I would end up with a line that contains the variable name and its value that would need to be updated. So, for example, I might end up with two variables like:

```
KEY="age"
VAL="21"
```

after it processes the first line of the following file:

```
age|21
name|bill
```

How would I assign the VAL value to the ABC struct variable KEY?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

So I'm looking to do something like:

```
ABC.KEY = VAL
```

meaning

```
ABC.age = 21
```

Comment: where is key in abc struct?

Comment: Has KEY and name the same meaning ? you thinking about assigning abc v; v.name = "age"; v.age=stoi ("21"); propably. Btw it is good practice to declare types with upper case letters. However question is a little bit unclear.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the response! Wouldn't I access the variables using ABC.age and ABC.name given the example?  And yes, KEY will ultimately have the value of 'age' and 'name' as it processes their respective lines of the file.

Comment: @InQusitive KEY would just be a variable that was created to process the values in a text file.

Comment: You may use a function which checks for the type and set the value

Comment: Thanks again InQusitive, but I'm trying to dynamically update the values stored in a structure based on the values read from a text file.  I'm not sure what checking for the type will be needed.  I will already have the structure variable to change as the first value of each line in the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as reflection, and C++ does not offer this capability.

If you want to match keys to members of the struct, you will have to build a structure and functions to do so yourself.

For example, you may consider this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string, abc&)>> mapping;
mapping["age"] = [](std::string str, abc& a) { a.age = std::stoi(str); };
mapping["name"] = [](std::string str, abc& a) { a.name = str; }
```

Now you can use the map like

```
abc output;
auto key = ...;
auto value = ...;
if (mapping.find(key) == mapping.end())
    throw ...;
mapping[key](value, output);
```

Comment: Thanks puppy.  Everything I have seen tries to setup objects and all kinds of things.  I'm just trying to keep things as simple as possible. What would a simplistic function look like to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: What you want to do is not simple, so there is no such thing. The easiest structures to use entail building a mapping from one to another that can be simple to navigate.

Comment: Really?!  I was using maps successfully before, but was told that was not a good option.  I switched to using structures and now it looks like I've traded one problem for another.

Comment: Not sure I follow your suggestion - "building a mapping from one to another"?

Comment: Well, this approach does not involve actually storing data inside the map. It only uses the map to define how the input keys relate to the structure members. Once you are done parsing the input you can throw the map away. The other parts of your program don't need to know anything about how you came by the values in the structure. Also, compared to reading the file, there's no way that a few map lookups are going to be slow.

Comment: Really, you should only change your code to get better speed if your profiler already told you that you need better speed in that part of your code... it's a stupid idea to change it randomly in hopes of better speed when you don't even know if you need more speed. Never take performance advice from anyone without at least telling them that it's a hotpath and what your profiler revealed about this hotpath. The real advantage to the structure is how strict and type-safe it is and how it doesn't leak information about how you retrieve the values... nothing to do with performance.

Comment: This is for storing visual info for a window manager (which requires good efficiency).  It just needs to be processed during the software init so that the rest of the program can refer directly to the structure values instead of having to continuely convert mapped string values to integers and such.  Like you said yours is just providing a temporary bridge between the two and then the map can be discarded.  Verifying this will work...

Comment: It doesn't require good efficiency in general. It requires good efficiency *in the hot path*, which is a *totally separate requirement*. If you actually needed high efficiency reading these values, they would not be stored in a textual format, just for example.

Comment: Is there a way to assign the link between the map and the structure with a 'for' loop at all?  There are several many variables in the structure.

Comment: Not without language-level reflection.

Comment: Ok.  And yeah, reading the file doesn't require the speed increase, just the operation of the software itself.