# Is it possible to access variable UI members with name?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QWidget` which I have attached to the toolbar of a `QMainWindow`. I would like to change the color of the pushbutton text when the buttons are activated. I realize that I could create a method for each pushbutton (example below), but I am wondering if I could create one method that uses the name of the desired pushbutton (pseudocode below).

**Change Specific pushbutton:**

```
void ToolBarClass::changeOKbutton(QColor color)
{
    ui->pushbutton_ok->[however text color is changed](color);
}
```

**Change variable pushbutton**

```
void ToolBarClass::changePushButton(QString buttonName, QColor color)
{
    ui->[accessUImemberByName](buttonName)->[however text color is changed](color);
}
```

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494658/dynamically-assigning-value-to-structure-variable) because I am looking for Qt specific functionality to access ui members by name, which appears to be very different from the "duplicate" question.

Comment: I suspect you need to implement this yourself using the result of findChildren()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QObject::objectName()` function, like below,

```
    void ToolBarClass::changePushButton(QString buttonName, QColor color)
    {
        QList< QPushButton* > listBtnAll = findChildren< QPushButton* >();
        for ( int i = 0; i < listBtnAll.size(); i++ )
        {
            if ( listBtnAll[ i ]->objectName() == buttonName )
            {
                listBtnAll[ i ]->[however text color is changed](color);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As @Pie_Jesu's advice, I've changed code, like below,

```
    void ToolBarClass::changePushButton(QString buttonName, QColor color)
    {
        QPushButton *pButton = findChild<QPushButton *>( buttonName ); 
        if ( pButton )
        {
            pButton->[however text color is changed](color);
        }
    }
```

I think the cost of search time is same, however, the cost of typing is more efficient than old code.

Comment: a huge part of your example can be simplified, if `findChildren` is replaced  with `findChild` method.

Comment: @Pie_Jesu: I've changed my code. Thanks for your advice.